# PHP - imagick extension

Tags: php, image, xampp

I am trying to install php [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension.
For that I installed Image Magic on windows 7 and it works fine.
when I am trying to enable Image Magick extension it doesn't work

System Specifications:

**PHP - 5.3.5**

**Windows - 7 (64 bit)**

Followed steps:

```
1. php_imagick.dll is placed in php/ext


2. other core dll files in apache/bin


3 .Edited php.ini : extension=php_imagick.dll

4. Restarted Apache.
```

But not able to work it out.

Please suggest where its going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try restart Apache after your changes?

Comment: Yes i restarted apache..

Comment: Try test if "extension_dir" in php.ini pointed to correct directory then. Or you can  try "extension=C:\\FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_DLL_DIR\\php_imagick.dll"

Comment: extension_dir is correct and even i tried with the full path but no lucky still its not working.

Comment: Good, just to be sure - You  try to find info about php_imagick in phpinfo() method output, right?

Comment: yes .. and tried to check with the test code also but its giving me the error .Class 'imagick' not found

Comment: Do the usual troubleshooting: ensure binaries match (32/64 bit, VC version, thread safety) and launch php from command line in order to see error messages.

Comment: Try to install diffrent version of imagick

Comment: Also - try investigate phpinfo() output - probably you are editing "php.ini" from wrong source or you can notice other nuances in it..